# RTTTL Obfuscation

Tags: popularity-contest, hello-world, music, obfuscation

**RTTTL**, or *Ring Tone Text Transfer Language* is a music format that was invented by Nokia <s>in the dawn of time when dinosaurs roamed the land</s>. It allows for fairly crude pieces of music (no chords or anything), and the format is pretty simple which is why I think it's pretty cool. Take a look at this one:

```
DejaVu: d=8,o=5,b=200: e, e, c, e, g, 2g4
```

Let's dissect the format. The "DejaVu" part at the beginning is the title -- this cannot be longer than ten characters. The d and o are the default values for duration and octave -- if a note doesn't specify duration or octave, it'll use these. Finally, the b is the beats per minute.

After that, the actual notes of the song are listed. The format of a note is DPO, where D is the duration of the note (1, 2, 4, 8, 16), P is the pitch (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,A#,B#,C#,D#,E#,F#,G#), and O is the octave (4-8 in the Nokia implementation, however it is different for other implementations. For the purposes of the challenge we'll say it is 1-8). If the duration or the octave is not specified, the defaults are used. Additionally, a note can have a dot after it -- this essentially multiplies the duration by 1.5.

In our example here, we have two E notes with no duration and octave, which mean that they have the default duration and octave (8, or eighth-note and octave 5), a C with no duration and octave, an E and a G. The final note is a G note with a duration of 2 (half-note) and an octave of 4.

Now that we've gone over the format, what's the challenge? The challenge actually doesn't have too much to do with RTTTL. Your task is to create an obfuscated program that outputs "Hello, World!" (exactly) that is also **a valid RTTTL song that is at least five seconds long**.

In order to test your RTTTL song, you can use [this site](http://merwin.bespin.org/t4aphp/) to convert your song to a MIDI file, then listen to it in a MIDI player. This is [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest). Good luck!

EDIT: Here's a website for converting MIDIs to RTTTLs if you so desire. [Link](http://midi.mathewvp.com/midi2RTTL.php)

EDIT2: This shiny bounty will be awarded to the winner (most upvoted post) in 7 days.

Comment: Can the beats per second be a decimal?

Comment: No. Also that was supposed to be beats per minute, I've fixed that.

Comment: Is there any way to convert a midi file to an RTTTL song?

Comment: I'm sure there is. Maybe try googling it? (You'd have to make sure the MIDI file doesn't contain chords, which RTTTL doesn't support.)

Comment: Found one that works: http://midi.mathewvp.com/midi2RTTL.php

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this challenge please explain why they downvoted it? It's really important that I get feedback so I can make better challenges in the future.

Comment: The challenge itself looks pretty hard, so instead I wrote a script to play the tunes. (It's not golfed). [PowerShell / Console Beep based `Play-RTTTL.ps1`](http://pastebin.com/unDa5f3a), and found some [example songs online](http://ez4mobile.com/nokiatone/rtttf.htm).

Comment: Updated the question to make octaves 1-8. If you guys are writing any RTTTL players I recommend you change them. The Nokia implementation does indeed use 4-8 but the format can handle 1-8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Whitespace, 2748 Bytes

(replace `\t` with actual tabs)

```
Hello:d=4, o=5, b=120:2p, 16a2,
16p, 16a2, 16p, 16a3,\t16p, 16a3, 16p,\t16g2, 16p, 16g2, 16p,
16g3,\t16p,\t16g3, 16p, 16a2, 16p, e3,\td3,
16b2, 16c3, 16b2, 16a2,\t8g2,\t16a2, 16p, 16a2,\t16p, 16a3,\t16p,
16a3,\t16p,\t16g2, 16p, 16g2, 16p, 16g3,\t16p, 16g3,
16p, 16a2, 16p, e3,\td3,\t16b2, 16c3,\t16b2,\t16a2, 8g2, 16a2,
16p,\t16a2,\t16p, 16a3, 16p, 16a3, 16p,\t16g2,\t16p,
16g2, 16p, 16g3, 16p,\t16g3,\t16p, 16a2,\t16p,\te3, d3, 16b2,
16c3,\t16b2,\t16a2, 8g2, 16a2, 16p, 16a2,\t16p, 16a3, 16p,
16a3, 16p, 16g2, 16p,\t16g2,\t16p, 16g3,\t16p,\t16g3,\t16p,\t16a2,
16p,\te3,\td3, 16b2, 16c3, 16b2, 16a2,\t8g2, 16a2,\t16p,
16a2, 16p, 16a3, 16p,\t16a3, 16p,\t16g2,\t16p, 16g2, 16p,
16g3,\t16p,\t16g3, 16p, 16a2, 16p, e3,\td3,\t16b2, 16c3,
16b2, 16a2, 8g2, 16a2,\t16p, 16a2, 16p, 16a3, 16p, 16a3,
16p,\t16g2,\t16p, 16g2, 16p, 16g3, 16p,\t16g3,\t16p,\t16a2,
16p, e3, d3, 16b2,\t16c3,\t16b2,\t16a2, 8g2,\ta2,\t8c#3,\t8e3,
g2,\t8b2,\t8d3, a2, 8c#3, 8e3, g2,\t8b2, 8d3, a2, 8c#3,
8e3, g2, 8b2, 8d3,\ta2,\t8c#3, 8e3,\tg2,\t8b2,\t8d3,\ta2,
8c#3,\t8e3,\tg2, 8b2, 8d3, a2, 8c#3,\t8e3, g2, 8b2,\t8d3,
a2, 8c#3, 8e3, g2,\t8b2,\t8d3,\ta2, 8c#3, 8e3,\tg2, 8b2,
8d3,\t16a2,\t16p, 16a2, 16p, 16a3, 16p,\t16a3, 16p,\t16g2, 16p,
16g2, 16p, 16g3, 16p,\t16g3,\t16p, 16a2,\t16p,\te3, d3, 16b2,
16c3,\t16b2,\t16a2, 8g2, 16a2, 16p, 16a2,\t16p, 16a3,\t16p,\t16a3,
16p, 16g2, 16p, 16g2,\t16p,\t16g3, 16p, 16g3,\t16p, 16a2, 16p,
e3,\td3,\t16b2, 16c3, 16b2, 16a2, 8g2,\t16a2,\t16p, 16a2, 16p,
16a3, 16p, 16a3, 16p,\t16g2, 16p, 16g2, 16p, 16g3,\t16p,
16g3,\t16p,\t16a2, 16p, e3, d3, 16b2,\t16c3,\t16b2, 16a2,\t8g2,
16a2, 16p, 16a2, 16p,\t16a3,\t16p, 16a3,\t16p,
16g2,\t16p,\t16g2, 16p, 16g3, 16p, 16g3,\t16p,\t16a2,\t16p, e3,
d3, 16b2, 16c3, 16b2,\t16a2, 8g2,\ta2, 8c#3,
8e3,\tg2,\t8b2, 8d3, a2, 8c#3, 8e3,\tg2,\t8b2,\t8d3,\ta2,
8c#3, 8e3, g2, 8b2, 8d3,
a2,\t8c#3,\t8e3, g2, 8b2, 8d3, a2, 8c#3,
8e3,
g2, 8b2, 8d3, a2, 8c#3,\t8e3,
g2, 8b2,
8d3, a2,\t8c#3,\t8e3,\tg2, 8b2,
8d3, a2,
8c#3,\t8e3, g2, 8b2,\t8d3, 1a3,
1a2,\td3,
8f#3, 8a3, c3, 8e3, 8g3, d3,\t8f#3,
8a3,\tc3, 8e3, 8g3, d3,
8f#3, 8a3,
c3, 8e3, 8g3,\td3,
8f#3,
8a3, c3, 8e3, 8g3,\td3, 8f#3,
8a3,
c3,
8e3,
8g3,d3,8f#3,8a3,c3,8e3,8g3,d3,8f#3,8a3,c3,8e3,8g3,d3,8f#3,8a3,c3,8e3,8g3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,8c3,274p,8b2,274c3,8p,8c#3,8d3,274p,8f3,274p,8d3,8c#3,
```

It's a horrible ringtone version of The Doors with *Hello, I love you*.

[Download converted MIDI](http://merwin.bespin.org/t4aphp/index.php?rtttlstring=Hello%3Ad%3D4%2C+o%3D5%2C+b%3D120%3A2p%2C+16a2%2C%0D%0A16p%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C+16a3%2C%0916p%2C+16a3%2C+16p%2C%0916g2%2C+16p%2C+16g2%2C+16p%2C%0D%0A16g3%2C%0916p%2C%0916g3%2C+16p%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C+e3%2C%09d3%2C%0D%0A16b2%2C+16c3%2C+16b2%2C+16a2%2C%098g2%2C%0916a2%2C+16p%2C+16a2%2C%0916p%2C+16a3%2C%0916p%2C%0D%0A16a3%2C%0916p%2C%0916g2%2C+16p%2C+16g2%2C+16p%2C+16g3%2C%0916p%2C+16g3%2C%0D%0A16p%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C+e3%2C%09d3%2C%0916b2%2C+16c3%2C%0916b2%2C%0916a2%2C+8g2%2C+16a2%2C%0D%0A16p%2C%0916a2%2C%0916p%2C+16a3%2C+16p%2C+16a3%2C+16p%2C%0916g2%2C%0916p%2C%0D%0A16g2%2C+16p%2C+16g3%2C+16p%2C%0916g3%2C%0916p%2C+16a2%2C%0916p%2C%09e3%2C+d3%2C+16b2%2C%0D%0A16c3%2C%0916b2%2C%0916a2%2C+8g2%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C+16a2%2C%0916p%2C+16a3%2C+16p%2C%0D%0A16a3%2C+16p%2C+16g2%2C+16p%2C%0916g2%2C%0916p%2C+16g3%2C%0916p%2C%0916g3%2C%0916p%2C%0916a2%2C%0D%0A16p%2C%09e3%2C%09d3%2C+16b2%2C+16c3%2C+16b2%2C+16a2%2C%098g2%2C+16a2%2C%0916p%2C%0D%0A16a2%2C+16p%2C+16a3%2C+16p%2C%0916a3%2C+16p%2C%0916g2%2C%0916p%2C+16g2%2C+16p%2C%0D%0A16g3%2C%0916p%2C%0916g3%2C+16p%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C+e3%2C%09d3%2C%0916b2%2C+16c3%2C%0D%0A16b2%2C+16a2%2C+8g2%2C+16a2%2C%0916p%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C+16a3%2C+16p%2C+16a3%2C%0D%0A16p%2C%0916g2%2C%0916p%2C+16g2%2C+16p%2C+16g3%2C+16p%2C%0916g3%2C%0916p%2C%0916a2%2C%0D%0A16p%2C+e3%2C+d3%2C+16b2%2C%0916c3%2C%0916b2%2C%0916a2%2C+8g2%2C%09a2%2C%098c%233%2C%098e3%2C%0D%0Ag2%2C%098b2%2C%098d3%2C+a2%2C+8c%233%2C+8e3%2C+g2%2C%098b2%2C+8d3%2C+a2%2C+8c%233%2C%0D%0A8e3%2C+g2%2C+8b2%2C+8d3%2C%09a2%2C%098c%233%2C+8e3%2C%09g2%2C%098b2%2C%098d3%2C%09a2%2C%0D%0A8c%233%2C%098e3%2C%09g2%2C+8b2%2C+8d3%2C+a2%2C+8c%233%2C%098e3%2C+g2%2C+8b2%2C%098d3%2C%0D%0Aa2%2C+8c%233%2C+8e3%2C+g2%2C%098b2%2C%098d3%2C%09a2%2C+8c%233%2C+8e3%2C%09g2%2C+8b2%2C%0D%0A8d3%2C%0916a2%2C%0916p%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C+16a3%2C+16p%2C%0916a3%2C+16p%2C%0916g2%2C+16p%2C%0D%0A16g2%2C+16p%2C+16g3%2C+16p%2C%0916g3%2C%0916p%2C+16a2%2C%0916p%2C%09e3%2C+d3%2C+16b2%2C%0D%0A16c3%2C%0916b2%2C%0916a2%2C+8g2%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C+16a2%2C%0916p%2C+16a3%2C%0916p%2C%0916a3%2C%0D%0A16p%2C+16g2%2C+16p%2C+16g2%2C%0916p%2C%0916g3%2C+16p%2C+16g3%2C%0916p%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C%0D%0Ae3%2C%09d3%2C%0916b2%2C+16c3%2C+16b2%2C+16a2%2C+8g2%2C%0916a2%2C%0916p%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C%0D%0A16a3%2C+16p%2C+16a3%2C+16p%2C%0916g2%2C+16p%2C+16g2%2C+16p%2C+16g3%2C%0916p%2C%0D%0A16g3%2C%0916p%2C%0916a2%2C+16p%2C+e3%2C+d3%2C+16b2%2C%0916c3%2C%0916b2%2C+16a2%2C%098g2%2C%0D%0A16a2%2C+16p%2C+16a2%2C+16p%2C%0916a3%2C%0916p%2C+16a3%2C%0916p%2C%0D%0A16g2%2C%0916p%2C%0916g2%2C+16p%2C+16g3%2C+16p%2C+16g3%2C%0916p%2C%0916a2%2C%0916p%2C+e3%2C%0D%0Ad3%2C+16b2%2C+16c3%2C+16b2%2C%0916a2%2C+8g2%2C%09a2%2C+8c%233%2C%0D%0A8e3%2C%09g2%2C%098b2%2C+8d3%2C+a2%2C+8c%233%2C+8e3%2C%09g2%2C%098b2%2C%098d3%2C%09a2%2C%0D%0A8c%233%2C+8e3%2C+g2%2C+8b2%2C+8d3%2C%0D%0Aa2%2C%098c%233%2C%098e3%2C+g2%2C+8b2%2C+8d3%2C+a2%2C+8c%233%2C%0D%0A8e3%2C%0D%0Ag2%2C+8b2%2C+8d3%2C+a2%2C+8c%233%2C%098e3%2C%0D%0Ag2%2C+8b2%2C%0D%0A8d3%2C+a2%2C%098c%233%2C%098e3%2C%09g2%2C+8b2%2C%0D%0A8d3%2C+a2%2C%0D%0A8c%233%2C%098e3%2C+g2%2C+8b2%2C%098d3%2C+1a3%2C%0D%0A1a2%2C%09d3%2C%0D%0A8f%233%2C+8a3%2C+c3%2C+8e3%2C+8g3%2C+d3%2C%098f%233%2C%0D%0A8a3%2C%09c3%2C+8e3%2C+8g3%2C+d3%2C%0D%0A8f%233%2C+8a3%2C%0D%0Ac3%2C+8e3%2C+8g3%2C%09d3%2C%0D%0A8f%233%2C%0D%0A8a3%2C+c3%2C+8e3%2C+8g3%2C%09d3%2C+8f%233%2C%0D%0A8a3%2C%0D%0Ac3%2C%0D%0A8e3%2C%0D%0A8g3%2Cd3%2C8f%233%2C8a3%2Cc3%2C8e3%2C8g3%2Cd3%2C8f%233%2C8a3%2Cc3%2C8e3%2C8g3%2Cd3%2C8f%233%2C8a3%2Cc3%2C8e3%2C8g3%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C8c3%2C274p%2C8b2%2C274c3%2C8p%2C8c%233%2C8d3%2C274p%2C8f3%2C274p%2C8d3%2C8c%233%2C&submitbutton=Choose+Conversion+Method)

Comment: My player doesn't like it `octave: 2, Cannot index into a null array.`. The question said only octaves 4-8 are valid, so that's all I coded it for. Sounds good on the linked website, though.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about this. Some players will support more octaves and some won't. The standard Nokia one only supports 4-8 which is why I mentioned that.

Answer (score 8):

## H9+, 157,007 bytes

[MIDI!!!!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ol5txgvgfn53814/anthem.mid?dl=0)

Is too long for the post. So here, have [a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/n2aCyU19). (The pastebin doesn't have proper capitalization, FYI.) I used the following softwares:

- `.MP3 => .MID`
- `.MID => .RTL`

The song is "Anthem of our Dying Day", by Story of the Year. It is the full, 3.5 minute song. `^-^`.

It starts out with:

```
ANTHEM:d=4,o=5,b=120:172c#,86f#,86a4,172p,16p,43a4,86p,43f#4,172a4,10p,57a4,...
```

`H`, of course, prints `Hello, World!`. And there are no `9`s nor `+`s in the code, I made sure. Good thing this isn't a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: Magnifique. +1 for you

Comment: @quartata _Merci!_

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like a herd of llamas are running around on 10 pianos, is that intended, or some playback problem on my side?

Comment: @aditsu It sort of is; it's just a rather intense rock song.

Comment: -1 doesn't implement spec ("*that outputs "Hello, World!" (exactly)*") and [isn't written in a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2028/194).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Acknowledged.

Comment: Most of your note durations are invalid

Comment: @aditsu ANd yet, somehow, it still works. There's a MIDI, isn't there?

Comment: That's because that site can handle some invalid values, not because you are using the correct format.

Answer (score 7):

## [123](https://esolangs.org/wiki/123), 816 Bytes

```
H:d=4,o=4,b=400:2a,2b,2a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,3b,3a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,1a,3b,1a,2b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,1a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,3a,3b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,3a,1b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,1a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,3a,3b,2a,1b,1a,3b,3a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,1b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,3a,3b,1a,1b,2a,3b,3a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,1a,1b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,1b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,1a,1b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,1b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,1a,1b,1a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,1b,3a,3b,1a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,3a,1b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,2a,2b,1a,1b,2a,1b,1a,1b,3a,3b,2a,1b,1a,3b,3a,1b,2a,1b,1a,2b,1a
```

[Download tune](http://merwin.bespin.org/t4aphp/index.php?rtttlstring=H%3Ad%3D4%2Co%3D4%2Cb%3D400%3A2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C3b%2C3a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C3b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C3a%2C3b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C3a%2C1b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C3a%2C3b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C3b%2C3a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C3a%2C3b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C3b%2C3a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C1b%2C3a%2C3b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C3a%2C1b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C2a%2C2b%2C1a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C1b%2C3a%2C3b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C3b%2C3a%2C1b%2C2a%2C1b%2C1a%2C2b%2C1a&submitbutton=Choose+Conversion+Method)

This one is just rhythmic beeping, but the language surely has more potential for this challenge, since in 123, all characters except 1, 2 and 3 are ignored. Credits for the original 123 code go to [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55644/43220).

Comment: Wow, never seen this language before. Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7, 1606 bytes

Okay, so it's not amazingly obfuscated, but it does work. I've [converted](http://merwin.bespin.org/t4aphp/) it to a midi file and it does play.

The tune is *[Still Alive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6ljFaKRTrI)* from [Portal](http://store.steampowered.com/app/400/). I got the tune as a midi file from [here](http://sheethost.com/sheet/ikwE8l), which I then [converted](http://midi.mathewvp.com/midi2RTTL.php) into a RTTL. The last few notes are off, but I think that's okay.

```
print[':d=4,o=5,b=120:2p,8g,8f#,8e,8e,2f#,1p,8a4,8g,8f#,8e,e,f#.,d,8e,1a4,8p,8a4,e,8f#,g.,8e,c#,d.,e,8a4,a4,1f#,2p,8g,8f#,8e,8e,2f#,1p,8a4,8g,8f#,8e,e.,8f#,d.,8e,2a4,2p,e,8f#,g.,8e,c#.,8d,e,8a4,8d,8e,8f,8e,8d,8c,p,8a4,8a#4,c,f,8e,8d,8d,8c,8d,8c,c,c,8a4,8a#4,c,f,8g,8f,8e,8d,8d,8e,f,f,8g,8a,8a#,8a#,a,g,8f,8g,8a,8a,g,f,8d,8c,8d,8f,8f,e,8e,8f#,8f#,8a,8d6,8f#6,8d6,8b,8d6,8f#6,8d6,8a,8d6,8f#6,8d6,8b,8d6,8f#6,8d6,8a,8d6,8f#6,8d6,8b,8d6,8f#6,8d6,p.,8a4,8g,8f#,8e,8e.,2f#,1p,8a4,8g,8f#,8e,e.,8f#,d,e,2a4,2p,e,8f#,g.,e,c#,8d,e.,8a4,a4,2f#,2p,8a4,8p,8b,8p,8a,8p,8g,8p,8g,8p,a,1p,8a4,8p,8b,8p,8a,8p,8g,8p,g.,p.,8a,8p,f#.,p.,8g,8p,2d,2p,e,8f#,g.,e,c#,8d,e,8a4,8d,8e,8f,8e,8d,c.,8a4,8a#4,c,f,8e,8d,8d,8c,8d,8c,c,c,8a4,8a#4,c,f,8g,8f,8e,8d,8d,8e,f,f,8g,8a,8a#,8a#,8a,8a,g,8f,8g,8a,8a,8g,8f,f,8d,8c,8d,8f,8f,e,8e,8f#,2f#,1p,8a4,8g,8f#,8e,8e.,2f#,1p,8a4,8g,8f#,8e,e.,8f#,d,e,2a4,2p,e,8f#,g.,e,c#,8d,e.,8a4,a4,2f#,2p,8a4,8p,8b,8p,8a,8p,8g,8p,8g,8p,a,1p,8a4,8p,8b,8p,8a,8p,8g,8p,g.,p.,8a,8p,f#.,p.,8g,8p,2d,2p,e,8f#,g.,e,c#,8d,e,8a4,8d,8e,8f,8e,8d,c.,8a4,8a#4,c,f,8e,8d,8d,8c,8d,8c,c,c,8a4,8a#4,c,f,8g,8f,8e,8d,8d,8e,f,f,8g,8a,8a#,8a#,8a,8a,g,8f,8g,8a,8a,8g,8f,f,8d,8c,8d,8f,8f,e,8e,8f#,8f#,2a,8p,8a,8a,512p,8a,512p,8b,512p,8a,512p,8f#,512p,d,p,8g,8p,8a,8p,2a,8p,8a,8a,512p,8a,512p,8b,512p,8a,512p,8f#,512p,d,p,8g,8p,8a,8p,2a,8p,8a,8a,512p,8a,512p,8b,512p,8a,512p,8f#,512p,d,p,8g,8p,8a,8p,2a,8p,8a,8a,512p,8a,512p,8b,512p,8a,512p,8f#,512p,d,p,8g,8p,8a,8p,2a,8p,8a,8a,512p,8a,512p,8b,512p,8a,512p,8f#,512p,d,p,8g,8p,8a,8p,a.,p.,8g,8a,a.,p.,8g,8f#,2f#',''.join(map(chr,[72,101,108,108,111,44,32,87,111,114,108,100,33]))][1]
```

Comment: Looks like it switched around the melody and backing/counter-melody parts in various places. There might be a version with just the melody somewhere.

Comment: Um.. your program doesn't seem to be a valid RTTTL song

Comment: @aditsu The only way I can check if its valid is by converting it to a midi file, so uh... you'll have to tell me how it's invalid.

Comment: Well, `2f#'` doesn't seem to be a valid note, and neither is `''.join(map(chr`, etc.

Comment: @aditsu I can not locate any documentation on RTTTL that suggests such characters are invalid. I don't know how to load it into a phone, but I can convert the entire code to a midi file and that plays without crashing.

Comment: It's right here in the challenge text: "The format of a note is DPO, where D is the duration of the note […]" - read the whole paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

## Lenguage

```
Hello: d=8,o=4,b=130: a, b, 4e5, a, b, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, f, a, 4e5, f, a, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, f, a, 4e5, a, b, 4e5, a, b, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, f, a, 4e5, f, a, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, f, a, e5, e, 4e, a, 4a., b, 4b., c5, 4c.5, 4d.5, 4c5, 2d5, p, g, b, 4e5, f, a, e5, e, e, 4a, 4a, 4b, 4b, 4c5, 2c5, b, c5, 4b, 2a, p, g, b, 4e5, f, a, e5, e, 4e, a, 4a., b, 4b., c5, 4c.5, 4d.5, 4c5, 2d5, p, g, b, 4e5, f, a, e5, d5, 2e5, a, b, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, g, b, d5, c5, e5, 4d.5, d5, c5, 4e5, a, c#5, 4e5, a, c#5, d5, e5, f5, e5, e5, d5, 2d5, g, b, 4d5, g, b, c5, d5, e5, d5, d5, c5, c5, g, 4a, f, a, 4c5, f, a, a#, c5, 4d.5, 4c.5, c5, a#, 4a, 2g#, f#, g#, 4a, a, 4b, a, 4c5, a, c5, 4e5, a, c5, d5, e5, 4f5, f5, 4f5, e5, 4d5, g, b, 4d5, g, b, c5, d5, 4e5, f5, 4e5, d5, c5, g, 2a, f, a, a#, c5, 4d5, c5, 4c5, 4a#, 4a, 2g#., 2p., p, f#, g#, 2a, a, b, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, f, a, 4e5, f, a, 4e5, g, b, 4e5, f, a, 4e5, 4a, 4c#5, 1e5
```

Followed by many gazillions of spaces so that the total length is 150306725405247424813082671095009555930972306375297366901721134222563463360025683976401363734706798738542991492

[Convert and download](http://merwin.bespin.org/t4aphp/index.php?rtttlstring=Hello%3A+d%3D8%2Co%3D4%2Cb%3D130%3A+a%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+a%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+4e5%2C+a%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+a%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+e5%2C+e%2C+4e%2C+a%2C+4a.%2C+b%2C+4b.%2C+c5%2C+4c.5%2C+4d.5%2C+4c5%2C+2d5%2C+p%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+e5%2C+e%2C+e%2C+4a%2C+4a%2C+4b%2C+4b%2C+4c5%2C+2c5%2C+b%2C+c5%2C+4b%2C+2a%2C+p%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+e5%2C+e%2C+4e%2C+a%2C+4a.%2C+b%2C+4b.%2C+c5%2C+4c.5%2C+4d.5%2C+4c5%2C+2d5%2C+p%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+e5%2C+d5%2C+2e5%2C+a%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+d5%2C+c5%2C+e5%2C+4d.5%2C+d5%2C+c5%2C+4e5%2C+a%2C+c%235%2C+4e5%2C+a%2C+c%235%2C+d5%2C+e5%2C+f5%2C+e5%2C+e5%2C+d5%2C+2d5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4d5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+c5%2C+d5%2C+e5%2C+d5%2C+d5%2C+c5%2C+c5%2C+g%2C+4a%2C+f%2C+a%2C+4c5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+a%23%2C+c5%2C+4d.5%2C+4c.5%2C+c5%2C+a%23%2C+4a%2C+2g%23%2C+f%23%2C+g%23%2C+4a%2C+a%2C+4b%2C+a%2C+4c5%2C+a%2C+c5%2C+4e5%2C+a%2C+c5%2C+d5%2C+e5%2C+4f5%2C+f5%2C+4f5%2C+e5%2C+4d5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4d5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+c5%2C+d5%2C+4e5%2C+f5%2C+4e5%2C+d5%2C+c5%2C+g%2C+2a%2C+f%2C+a%2C+a%23%2C+c5%2C+4d5%2C+c5%2C+4c5%2C+4a%23%2C+4a%2C+2g%23.%2C+2p.%2C+p%2C+f%23%2C+g%23%2C+2a%2C+a%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+4e5%2C+g%2C+b%2C+4e5%2C+f%2C+a%2C+4e5%2C+4a%2C+4c%235%2C+1e5&submitbutton=Choose+Conversion+Method) (note: the code is truncated to save bandwidth, but the resulting midi should be the same)

Comment: Lionel Richie - "Hello" ?

Comment: @LukStorms yes! :)