# Play an RTTTL song

Tags: code-golf, music, audio

User quartata posted [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60147/7416), but he neglected the fact that, for whatever reason, he's not able to play MIDI files on his computer.

Let's help him out by writing a full program that reads a song in RTTTL format from the standard input, prints the song name to the standard output and plays it (at the right speed and pitch).

**Format details**

RTTTL is a fairly dumb and underspecified ringtone format. It consists of a name, some default values, and a series of notes (only one note at a time) in a simple text format.

Example: `fifth: d=4,o=5,b=63: 8P, 8G5, 8G5, 8G5, 2D#5`

The name is a string terminated by a colon. Here the name is "fifth". Your program must accept names with at least 15 characters.

Next, the defaults section (also terminated by a colon) lists some default values for duration (d), octave (o) and the beats per minute (b) for the song. They are comma-separated and use a "key=value" syntax. There may be any number of spaces around each "key=value" part. You may assume that default values d, o and b are all present, in this order. The duration and octave will be explained below; the bpm refers to the number of beats (corresponding to quarter notes) that should be played in a minute, and you must support any integer value between 20 and 900 (inclusive).

Then the actual song is listed as a comma-separated series of notes using a "DPO" syntax, where D is the duration, P is the pitch (note) and O is the octave. There may be any number of spaces and newlines around each "DPO" part.

The duration is a power of 2 between 1 and 32 (inclusive), representing a fraction of a whole note. So for example a value of 4 (quarter note) is twice as long as a value of 8 (eighth note). The duration can be missing, in which case the default duration will be used. The duration may also be modified by the presence of a dot (`.`), specifically the dot makes the note last 50% longer. Since not everybody agrees about where the dot is supposed to be, you must accept a dot after the pitch or after the octave (i.e. both "DP.O" and "DPO." should work).

The pitch is one of A,B,C,D,E,F,G,A#,C#,D#,F#,G#,P where A-G# are the standard musical notes (note: no flats, use the corresponding sharp note) and P is a pause. The pitch is the only part of the note that is required, and is case-insensitive.

And finally, the octave is a number normally from 4 to 8, but you must support any number from 1 to 8 inclusive. For example, C4 is the standard middle C with a frequency of about 261.63Hz. The octave can be missing, in which case the default octave will be used. You can assume that pauses don't have an octave specified (as it has no meaning).

As mentioned in the other challenge, you can use [this site](http://merwin.bespin.org/t4aphp/) to convert RTTTL songs to MIDI format for testing (but note that it may not follow the exact same specification).

**Requirements:**

Your program must play each note at the right speed and pitch. It can use any kind of sound (sine/triangle/square wave, piano sound, bell sound, whatever; also it can be a standard beep, wave sound or MIDI sound etc) as long as it is audible and the pitch is recognizable.

Each note must be played continuously for the specified duration or no more than a 64th note shorter than that, except if you're using something like an [ADSR envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#ADSR_envelope), in which case the release phase may continue through the next pause or over the next note.

If two consecutive notes have the same pitch, they must be clearly distinguished, either through a short break (using no more than the length of a 64th note, as part of the first note's duration) or by using a non-uniform sound (such as the ADSR envelope mentioned above), or at least through a [phase change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_change_(waves)) if it's clear enough. Two consecutive pauses should be treated the same as a single pause with the total duration.

The program must be runnable in Linux using freely available software. It should read the song from the standard input, and print the song name to the standard output.

If the input does not match the specification above, the behavior is unspecified. Your program may ignore errors, or print a message, or play something wrong, hang or crash, it should just not do any damage.

Standard loopholes are not allowed.

**Scoring**

Code golf, shortest program (measured in UTF-8 bytes) wins.

Comment: Do we have a restricted OS (i.e. no Linux-specific languages if running Windows)?

Comment: I believe aditsu is trying to be nice to me (:3) and make it only languages that run under Linux. I do have a really crummy old Mac laptop so feel free to make an AppleScript one

Comment: You knew exactly what I was going for. ;)

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE Linux-specific languages are fine, because the requirement is for the program to run in Linux (both for my and quartata's sake)

Comment: I don't have linux and so even if I knew how to write something on linux I couldn't test it.  If I write an exeecutable that uses Windows API can it be run in Wine or is that not allowed?  I think limiting it to linux is really limiting - kind of like those questions that limit answers to a particular programming language...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I think using wine is acceptable, I'll just need a way to compile the code. Basically, you could also post something that can't run in Linux, it just won't be eligible for my upvote or for winning the challenge.

Comment: Working on a Perl solution just so that I can imitate the greats (Dennis, Martin) and answer a challenge about me

Comment: is it okay to read from a file instead of stdin?

Comment: @LiamNoronha only if you can't read from stdin

Comment: how should three adjacent 64th-notes be separated? two 64th-gaps would erase the middle note.

Comment: @Sparr there can't be any 64th notes in the song according to the spec. Also, the gap should erase part of the current note.

Comment: Roger that on 32nd notes being the shortest. Not sure what you mean by "the current note", though. Is that the note before or after the gap? Or should it span the boundary? The spec is unclear.

Comment: @Sparr If you have 2 notes with the same pitch, and the duration of the first note is x and the duration a 64th note is y, and you want to use a gap, then you can choose a gap duration z <= y, and you should play the first note for the duration x-z, followed by a z gap. You can do the same thing for all notes, even if they are different.

Comment: @aditsu I understand what you're saying in the comments. My point is that the spec doesn't define that detail. if my two notes of the same pitch are of duration W and X, the spec doesn't say whether Z is to be subtracted from W or X or split between them. It just says "the note duration" without specifying WHICH note(s).

Comment: @Sparr updated, how's that?

Comment: update looks good.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 813

```java
import javax.sound.sampled.*;class R{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{Integer k=0;a=new
java.util.Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\A").next().split(":");System.out.println(a[0]);int[]X=new
int[3],N={9,11,0,2,4,5,7};while(k<3)X[k]=k.valueOf(a[1].split(",")[k++].split("=")[1].trim());SourceDataLine
l=AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(new AudioFormat(48000,8,1,1>0,1<0));l.open();l.start();for(String
t:a[2].toLowerCase().split(",")){a[k=0]=a[1]=a[2]="";for(char
c:t.trim().toCharArray())if(c!=46)a[k+=(c<48|c>57?1:0)^k]+=c;int
D=32/(a[k=0]==""?X[0]:k.valueOf(a[0]))*(t.contains(".")?3:2),m=a[1].charAt(0)-97,P=m>6?0:N[m]+12*(a[2]==""?X[1]:k.valueOf(a[2]))+(t.contains("#")?1:0);int
n=180000*D/X[2];for(;k<n;++k)l.write(new byte[]{(byte)(P>0&k<n-n/D?k*Math.pow(2,P/12.)/22.93:0)},0,1);}l.drain();}}
```

I'm still working on it.
It's a bit sensitive to CPU speed and busyness when starting.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 15186 bytes

**There's a link at the bottom where you can hear a sample**

I present one of the least practical ways to play music on your Linux machine:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
namespace N{double a = 440.;double as = 466.16;double b = 493.88;double c = 523.25;double cs = 554.37;double d = 587.33;double ds = 622.25;double e = 659.25;double f =  698.46;double fs = 739.99 ;double g =  783.99;double gs =  830.61;    const unsigned SAMPLES = 10*44100;const unsigned SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;const unsigned AMPLITUDE = 10000;const double TWO_PI = 6.28318;    sf::Int16 a4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 as4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 b4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 c4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 cs4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 d4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 ds4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 e4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 f4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 fs4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 g4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 gs4raw[SAMPLES];sf::Int16 pauseraw[SAMPLES];double inc = a/44100;double x=0;int i=0;void set1(){for(int i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){a4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}inc=as/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){as4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x += inc;}inc=b/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){b4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}inc=c/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){c4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE * sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}inc=cs/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){cs4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}inc=d/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){d4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}inc=ds/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){ds4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}inc=e/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){e4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}inc=f/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){f4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}inc=fs/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){fs4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}inc=g/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){g4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;} inc=gs/44100;x=0;for(unsigned i=0;i<SAMPLES;i++){gs4raw[i]=AMPLITUDE*sin(x*TWO_PI);x+=inc;}}sf::SoundBuffer a3; sf::SoundBuffer a4; sf::SoundBuffer a5; sf::SoundBuffer a6; sf::SoundBuffer a7;sf::SoundBuffer as3; sf::SoundBuffer as4; sf::SoundBuffer as5; sf::SoundBuffer as6; sf::SoundBuffer as7;sf::SoundBuffer b3; sf::SoundBuffer b4; sf::SoundBuffer b5; sf::SoundBuffer b6; sf::SoundBuffer b7;sf::SoundBuffer c3; sf::SoundBuffer c4; sf::SoundBuffer c5; sf::SoundBuffer c6; sf::SoundBuffer c7;sf::SoundBuffer cs3; sf::SoundBuffer cs4; sf::SoundBuffer cs5; sf::SoundBuffer cs6; sf::SoundBuffer cs7;sf::SoundBuffer d3; sf::SoundBuffer d4; sf::SoundBuffer d5; sf::SoundBuffer d6; sf::SoundBuffer d7;sf::SoundBuffer ds3; sf::SoundBuffer ds4; sf::SoundBuffer ds5; sf::SoundBuffer ds6; sf::SoundBuffer ds7;sf::SoundBuffer e3; sf::SoundBuffer e4; sf::SoundBuffer e5; sf::SoundBuffer e6; sf::SoundBuffer e7;sf::SoundBuffer f3; sf::SoundBuffer f4; sf::SoundBuffer f5; sf::SoundBuffer f6; sf::SoundBuffer f7;sf::SoundBuffer fs3; sf::SoundBuffer fs4; sf::SoundBuffer fs5; sf::SoundBuffer fs6; sf::SoundBuffer fs7;sf::SoundBuffer g3; sf::SoundBuffer g4; sf::SoundBuffer g5; sf::SoundBuffer g6; sf::SoundBuffer g7;sf::SoundBuffer gs3; sf::SoundBuffer gs4; sf::SoundBuffer gs5; sf::SoundBuffer gs6; sf::SoundBuffer gs7;sf::SoundBuffer pauseBuffer;void set2(){if (!a3.loadFromSamples(a4raw,SAMPLES,1,SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if(!a4.loadFromSamples(a4raw,SAMPLES,1,SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if(!a5.loadFromSamples(a4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if(!a6.loadFromSamples(a4raw,SAMPLES,1,SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if(!a7.loadFromSamples(a4raw,SAMPLES,1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}  if (!as3.loadFromSamples(as4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!as4.loadFromSamples(as4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!as5.loadFromSamples(as4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!as6.loadFromSamples(as4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!as7.loadFromSamples(as4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!b3.loadFromSamples(b4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!b4.loadFromSamples(b4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!b5.loadFromSamples(b4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!b6.loadFromSamples(b4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!b7.loadFromSamples(b4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!c3.loadFromSamples(c4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!c4.loadFromSamples(c4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!c5.loadFromSamples(c4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!c6.loadFromSamples(c4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!c7.loadFromSamples(c4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!cs3.loadFromSamples(cs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!cs4.loadFromSamples(cs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!cs5.loadFromSamples(cs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!cs6.loadFromSamples(cs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!cs7.loadFromSamples(cs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!d3.loadFromSamples(d4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!d4.loadFromSamples(d4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!d5.loadFromSamples(d4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!d6.loadFromSamples(d4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!d7.loadFromSamples(d4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!ds3.loadFromSamples(ds4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!ds4.loadFromSamples(ds4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!ds5.loadFromSamples(ds4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!ds6.loadFromSamples(ds4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!ds7.loadFromSamples(ds4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}    if (!e3.loadFromSamples(e4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!e4.loadFromSamples(e4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!e5.loadFromSamples(e4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!e6.loadFromSamples(e4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!e7.loadFromSamples(e4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!f3.loadFromSamples(f4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!f4.loadFromSamples(f4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!f5.loadFromSamples(f4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!f6.loadFromSamples(f4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!f7.loadFromSamples(f4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!fs3.loadFromSamples(fs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!fs4.loadFromSamples(fs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!fs5.loadFromSamples(fs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!fs6.loadFromSamples(fs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!fs7.loadFromSamples(fs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!g3.loadFromSamples(g4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!g4.loadFromSamples(g4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!g5.loadFromSamples(g4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!g6.loadFromSamples(g4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!g7.loadFromSamples(g4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!gs3.loadFromSamples(gs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE/2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!gs4.loadFromSamples(gs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!gs5.loadFromSamples(gs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*2)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!gs6.loadFromSamples(gs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*4)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if (!gs7.loadFromSamples(gs4raw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE*8)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}if(!pauseBuffer.loadFromSamples(pauseraw, SAMPLES, 1, SAMPLE_RATE)){std::cerr<<"err: load fail";}}sf::Sound A3; sf::Sound A4;sf::Sound A5;sf::Sound A6;sf::Sound A7;sf::Sound AS3; sf::Sound AS4;sf::Sound AS5;sf::Sound AS6;sf::Sound AS7;sf::Sound B3; sf::Sound B4;sf::Sound B5;sf::Sound B6;sf::Sound B7;sf::Sound C3; sf::Sound C4;sf::Sound C5;sf::Sound C6;sf::Sound C7;sf::Sound CS3; sf::Sound CS4;sf::Sound CS5;sf::Sound CS6;sf::Sound CS7;sf::Sound D3; sf::Sound D4;sf::Sound D5;sf::Sound D6;sf::Sound D7;sf::Sound DS3; sf::Sound DS4;sf::Sound DS5;sf::Sound DS6;sf::Sound DS7;sf::Sound E3; sf::Sound E4;sf::Sound E5;sf::Sound E6;sf::Sound E7;sf::Sound F3; sf::Sound F4;sf::Sound F5;sf::Sound F6;sf::Sound F7;sf::Sound FS3; sf::Sound FS4;sf::Sound FS5;sf::Sound FS6;sf::Sound FS7;sf::Sound G3; sf::Sound G4;sf::Sound G5;sf::Sound G6;sf::Sound G7;sf::Sound GS3; sf::Sound GS4;sf::Sound GS5;sf::Sound GS6;sf::Sound GS7;sf::Sound pause;void set3(){A3.setBuffer(a3);A3.setLoop(true);A4.setBuffer(a4);A4.setLoop(true);A5.setBuffer(a5);A5.setLoop(true);A6.setBuffer(a6);A6.setLoop(true);A7.setBuffer(a7);A7.setLoop(true);AS3.setBuffer(as3);AS3.setLoop(true);AS4.setBuffer(as4);AS4.setLoop(true);AS5.setBuffer(as5);AS5.setLoop(true);AS6.setBuffer(as6);AS6.setLoop(true);AS7.setBuffer(as7);AS7.setLoop(true);B3.setBuffer(b3);B3.setLoop(true);B4.setBuffer(b4);B4.setLoop(true);B5.setBuffer(b5);B5.setLoop(true);B6.setBuffer(b6);B6.setLoop(true);B7.setBuffer(b7);B7.setLoop(true);C3.setBuffer(c3);C3.setLoop(true);C4.setBuffer(c4);C4.setLoop(true);C5.setBuffer(c5);C5.setLoop(true);C6.setBuffer(c6);C6.setLoop(true);C7.setBuffer(c7);C7.setLoop(true);D3.setBuffer(d3);D3.setLoop(true);D4.setBuffer(d4);D4.setLoop(true);D5.setBuffer(d5);D5.setLoop(true);D6.setBuffer(d6);D6.setLoop(true);D7.setBuffer(d7);D7.setLoop(true);DS3.setBuffer(ds3);DS3.setLoop(true);DS4.setBuffer(ds4);DS4.setLoop(true);DS5.setBuffer(ds5);DS5.setLoop(true);DS6.setBuffer(ds6);DS6.setLoop(true);DS7.setBuffer(ds7);DS7.setLoop(true);E3.setBuffer(e3);E3.setLoop(true);E4.setBuffer(e4);E4.setLoop(true);E5.setBuffer(e5);E5.setLoop(true);E6.setBuffer(e6);E6.setLoop(true);E7.setBuffer(e7);E7.setLoop(true);F3.setBuffer(f3);F3.setLoop(true);F4.setBuffer(f4);F4.setLoop(true);F5.setBuffer(f5);F5.setLoop(true);F6.setBuffer(f6);F6.setLoop(true);F7.setBuffer(f7);F7.setLoop(true);FS3.setBuffer(fs3);FS3.setLoop(true);FS4.setBuffer(fs4);FS4.setLoop(true);FS5.setBuffer(fs5);FS5.setLoop(true);FS6.setBuffer(fs6);FS6.setLoop(true);FS7.setBuffer(fs7);FS7.setLoop(true);G3.setBuffer(g3);G3.setLoop(true);G4.setBuffer(g4);G4.setLoop(true);G5.setBuffer(g5);G5.setLoop(true);G6.setBuffer(g6);G6.setLoop(true);G7.setBuffer(g7);G7.setLoop(true);GS3.setBuffer(gs3);GS3.setLoop(true);GS4.setBuffer(gs4);GS4.setLoop(true);GS5.setBuffer(gs5);GS5.setLoop(true);GS6.setBuffer(gs6);GS6.setLoop(true);GS7.setBuffer(gs7);GS7.setLoop(true);pause.setBuffer(pauseBuffer);pause.setLoop(true);}sf::Sound* naturalNotePtrs[7][5] = {{&A3,&A4,&A5,&A6,&A7}, {&B3,&B4,&B5,&B6,&B7}, {&C3,&C4,&C5,&C6,&C7}, {&D3,&D4,&D5,&D6,&D7}, {&E3,&E4,&E5,&E6,&E7}, {&F3,&F4,&F5,&F6,&F7}, {&G3,&G4,&G5,&G6,&G7}};sf::Sound* sharpNotePtrs[5][5]={   {&AS3,&AS4,&AS5,&AS6,&AS7}, {&CS3,&CS4,&CS5,&CS6,&CS7},  {&DS3,&DS4,&DS5,&DS6,&DS7},{&FS3,&FS4,&FS5,&FS6,&FS7},{&GS3,&GS4,&GS5,&GS6,&GS7}};sf::Sound getNote(char value, int octave, bool sharp){if (value =='p' || value=='P'){return A4;}if(sharp){switch(value){case 'a':return (*sharpNotePtrs[0][octave-3]);break;case 'c':return (*sharpNotePtrs[1][octave-3]);break;case 'd':return *sharpNotePtrs[2][octave-3];break;case 'f':return *sharpNotePtrs[3][octave-3];break;case 'g':return *sharpNotePtrs[4][octave-3];break;default:std::cerr<<"Invalid sharp\n";}}else {return *naturalNotePtrs[value-97][octave-3];}}void playNote(float duration,int bpm, char value, int octave, bool sharp) {sf::Clock clock;sf::Time time;sf::Sound sound;sound = getNote(value, octave,sharp);double beats=4/duration;double bps = bpm/60.;double trueTimeSecs = beats/bps;int sleepTime =trueTimeSecs*1000+1;while(1) {if(value!='p' && value!= 'P') {sound.play();}sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(sleepTime));time = clock.getElapsedTime();if(time.asSeconds()>trueTimeSecs){sound.stop();clock.restart();break;}}}}char upperToLower(char input) {if(input>='A'&&input<='Z') {return input+32;}else {return input;}}int main(){using namespace std;using namespace N;using namespace sf;set1();set2();set3();bool delFile=false;ifstream test("x.rtttl"); if(test.good()) {cout<<"no input necessary, 'x.rtttl' already exists and will be read, as is.\n";}else {ofstream outf("x.rtttl");string in;cout<<"Please enter your rtttl file manually, in one line:\n";getline(cin,in);outf<<in<<endl;outf.close();delFile=true;}ifstream song("x.rtttl");song.seekg(0,ios::beg);float duration=0.;int octave=4;int bpm=0;float noteDuration =0.;int noteOctave =0;char noteValue='a';bool sharp = false;bool readIntro = false;bool readData = false;char c;std::cout<< "Now Playing: ";while(song){song>>c;if(c==':'&& !readIntro){readIntro=true;}else if (c==':') { readIntro=false; readData=true;}if(!readIntro && !readData){std::cout<<c;}c=upperToLower(c);if(readIntro) {if(c=='d') {song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);duration = c-48;}if(c=='o'){song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);octave = c-48;}if(c=='b') {song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);int steps=0;while(c!=':'&&steps<5) {song>>c;steps++;}song.seekg(-steps-1, ios::cur);song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);if(steps==3) {bpm+=100*(c-48);song>>c;bpm+=10*(c-48);song>>c;bpm+=c-48;}if(steps==2){bpm+=10*(c-48);song>>c;bpm+=(c-48);}}}else if (readData){if(c<='9' && c>='0') {switch(c){case '1': song>>c;if(c=='6'){ noteDuration=16.;}else {noteDuration = 1.;}break;case '2': noteDuration = 2.;break;case '4':noteDuration = 4.;break;case'8':noteDuration =8.; break;case '3':noteDuration = 32.; song>>c; break;default:cerr<<"\nBad Duration:"<<c;return 1;}song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);noteValue = c;song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);if(c=='#'){sharp = true;song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);}else {sharp =false;}if(c<='9' && c>= '0' ) { noteOctave = c-48;song>>c;c=upperToLower(c); }else {noteOctave = octave;}if(c=='.'){noteDuration*=1.5; song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);}playNote(noteDuration,bpm, noteValue, noteOctave,sharp);}else if(c<='z' && c>='a') {noteDuration = duration;noteValue = c;song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);if(c=='#') { sharp = true;song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);}else {sharp =false;}if(c<='9' && c>= '0' ) { noteOctave = c-48;song>>c;c=upperToLower(c); }else {noteOctave = octave;}if(c=='.') { noteDuration*=1.5; song>>c;c=upperToLower(c);}playNote(noteDuration,bpm, noteValue, noteOctave,sharp);}}}if(delFile) {song.close();remove("x.rtttl");}return 0;}
```

I unfortunately I cannot include both the golfed and ungolfed code (space constraints), and the code could be golfed further.

A large part of the reason that the file is so long is that it has to create every pitch (12 notes * 5 octaves) individually using sine waves.

**Compiling** I compiled using the dev cmd prompt for visual studio, but it is very similar with g++ on Linux.

```
cl music.cpp /I SFML\SFML-2.3.1\include /link SFML\SFML-2.3.1\lib\sfml-system.lib SFML\SFML-2.3.1\lib\sfml-audio.lib
```

You just need to link things properly.

credit to [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) and [this post](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Play-Sine-Wave) for the idea.

I think the timings are correct, let me know if they are not.

**Give it a listen**

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnldtijrdgsypg2/2015-10-21-1537-29.wmv?dl=0) (Link to DropBox) is a screen recording of it playing a quick rendition of the Morrowind Theme that I whipped up. Note that in the video it doesn't ask for input because the file already exists.

```
MorrowindTheme: d=4,o=4,b=100: 8a, 8b, 2c, 8c, 8d, 2e, 8e, 8g, 2d, 16e, 16d, 8c, 8b, a, p,  8a, 8b, 2c, 8c, 8d, 2e, 8e, 8g, 2a5, g, 8b5, a5, 8a5, 8b5, c5, b5, a5, g, f, e, 2d, c, 8e, 2d, 8c, 8b, 1a
```

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/way-too-long-allowed-or-disallowed?cb=1

Comment: added accurate byte count

Comment: Still, you are supposed to make some effort to golf your code. And have you heard of input redirection?

Comment: First, I have heard of input redirection, but have never used it, so I opted to do something I was more familiar with. Is there a resource that indicates that code should be golfed? All I could find is this(http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/714/should-we-establish-rules-etiquette-for-posting-non-winning-answers/716#716 ). To be perfectly honest, I don't want to spend hours golfing this. If it isn't acceptable, I will remove it.

Comment: Actually I found this (http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25/code-golf-answers-that-arent-golfing-attempts)

Comment: Just saw your comments now. There is some relevant wording in the [help center](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but indeed it's not very easy to find. There's a general expectation here that code golf answers should be golfed. But I don't think you need to delete it (if you don't want to golf it).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me. I wasn't aware of that

Comment: Btw, you could draw my attention by writing "@aditsu"; normally only you get comment notifications on your own answer.

Comment: You don't need spaces between `#include` and the library. You can also use `#import` instead.

Comment: Oh no, not Morrowind... Now it won't stop playing in my head... once again... xD